# Nagios: Dependency from service to different host

Tags: nagios

We have a server "zibal" that is running several Selenium checks for websites on multiple hosts. At the moment, when one of the servers hosting a website goes down, the failing selenium check will also generate an (unnecessary) notification.

From the [Nagios documentation](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#servicedependency), it seems like it is only possible to add a dependency from a service to another service, or from a host to another host, but not from one service on "zibal" to server B as a host.

Another [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/150605/164732) states to use a parent definition (not sure if that case applies here). I have added such a parent definition (multiple hosts) to "zibal", but this doesn't look right: When server B goes down, there should be no notification for the failing Selenium check, but in case "zibal" goes down as well, there of course should be a notification.

How does this have to be configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You want [service dependencies](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/dependencies.html) for each Selenium check, in this case.

The Selenium check for "server B" depends on a service check that's on server B (for example, a check of the web server using `check_http`).

You can simplify the configuration using host and/or servicegroups with dependencies. See the [time-saving tips and tricks](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objecttricks.html#servicedependency) docs page for more info.